# TextView inside Recyclerview ViewHolder - OnClickListner

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a very simple `RecyclerView` and a `ViewHolder` as following

**ViewHolder**

```
 private class SENT_VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        public SENT_VH(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {                
            MyText = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sent_msg_time);
            DeleteButton = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sent_msg_person_name);               
            itemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
        }           
        public TextView DeleteButton { get; set; }          
        public TextView MyText { get; set; }           

        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            // ViewHolder Item clicked
        }          
    }
```

This work perfectly when I click on the item but I am trying to implement OnClickListner on `DeleteButton` as following

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        try
        {
            SENT_VH viewHolder = holder as SENT_VH;                            
            viewHolder.MyText.Text = itemList[position].userText;
            viewHolder.DeleteButton.SetOnClickListener(new DeleteOnClickListner(itemList[position].id, context, position));
        }
        catch (Exception X)
        {
            //LOG.Error >> ERROR
        }
    }
```

Finally my `DeleteOnClickListner` is

```
  class DeleteOnClickListner : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        private decimal id;
        private Context context;
        private int pos;
        public DeleteOnClickListner(decimal id, Context context, int pos)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.context = context;
            this.pos = pos;
        }
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("ADAPTER", "Delete id: " + id);
            ((MainActivity)context).deleteConfirmation(id, pos);
        }
    }
```

In the MainActivity for `deleteConfirmation` method I am just trying to get the position and id as following

```
public void deleteConfirmation(decimal id, int pos)
 {
    EVENT_LOGGER(TAG, "Pos:" + pos + ", id: " + id);
 }
```

The problem is I always get the same `id` and `position` as the first `DeleteButton` I click in any ViewHolder, it never changes.

For example, if I first clicked on the `DeleteButton` at item position 10, it keeps sending position 10 no matter which `DeleteButton` I click next.

Do you guys have any idea what is going on

> **EDIT:**

As suggested by @tyczj, I tried to move OnclickListner in my ViewHolder by adding the following in my ViewHolder

```
public void SetMyView(decimal id, Context context, int pos)
        {               
            DeleteButton.SetOnClickListener(new DeleteOnClickListner(id, context, pos));
        }
```

And Using SetMyView in my `OnBindViewHolder` as following

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    try
    {
        SENT_VH viewHolder = holder as SENT_VH;   
        viewHolder.SetMyView(position, context);  //This line here                       
        viewHolder.MyText.Text = itemList[position].userText;
        viewHolder.DeleteButton.SetOnClickListener(new DeleteOnClickListner(itemList[position].id, context, position));
    }
```

No Difference exactly the same result
catch (Exception X)
{
//LOG.Error >> ERROR
}
}

**`EDIT 2 - Working Solution`**

I updated the VH to just add the following

```
DeleteButton.SetOnClickListener(new DeleteOnClickListner(AdapterPosition));
```

Comment: Is this in Xamarin?

Comment: Yes, but you can give me java solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with your first method? its much easier to to use the ViewHolder than what you are doing

Make your viewholder an inner class of your adapter

Kotlin example

```
inner class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val MyText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.sent_msg_time)
    val DeleteButton : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.sent_msg_person_name)

    init {
        DeleteButton .setOnClickListener {
            ((MainActivity)context).deleteConfirmation(itemList[adapterPosition].id, adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

`adapterPosition` or `absoluteAdapterPosition` depending on the version of recyclerview you are using gives you the position of the viewholder

for your adapter pass in context to get your main activity (should be using an interface though to communicate back to the activity) and the list of items then you can get what you need a lot easier

Comment: Hey, cheers for the reply, I agree with using `interface`, I did however tried your suggestion, it didn't make a difference, Please see my EDIT in my question to ensure I understand your answer correctly.

Comment: @Ali I dont really see a difference from what you had, you just moved logic to the VH, you are not using adapterPosition (getAdapterPosition) or absoluteAdapterPosition (getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()) like I suggested which the VH gives you. You shouldnt need to pass anything addition to the VH, just create the click listener and thats it

Comment: got ya, cheers thanks :) This works and I also created the interface

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition` inside `ViewHolder` to get the Absolute position

Reference:
[getAbsoluteAdapterPosition | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition())

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution, I used `adapterPosition`, I didn't mark you as an answer as you did not write any code, as per StackOverflow rules whenever you answer please provide the working code. Although you were spot on I could not mark you an answer. I however upvoted you as its more or less the solution

Comment: ok I get it, I will try next time, thanks